# Retrieving View Table From SQL

Tags: asp.net

It's a bit silly question but is it possible to get Views from SQL as a table and use that without creating classes and fields in which we can hold records?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule in asking a question, you are encouraged to post some code and what you attempted.

but, yes, rather common to use a database "directly", and often such a database "first" type of coding is and can be adopted.

For those that came from desktop software such as VB6, ms-access, FoxPro, vb.net etc?

They also often just used SQL, or even SQL views to fill out, and load data into a web page.

So, for example, we can drop in a GridView onto a page, say this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table">

        </asp:GridView>
```

And, say the code behind can be this (we use  view in the sql).

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM VhotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQl, conn)
            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData As New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

So, really, any use of SQL in code?

You can quite much use a view the same way.